# RewriteRule to change URL with + is also affecting or not allowing second rule to change url with -

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Ok So i have my .htaccess file and i am rewriting a search query.

I have the query itself rewriting correctly, but the second half of the rewrite to actually create the virtual file or whatever you want to call what this voodoo is... has two rules that both work independently but not together... meaning if i put one before the other the first one works and the second one doesn't and if i swap them, the new first one works and the second doesn't.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)/([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /searchresults.php?search=1&year_search_type=single&isused=all&year=$1&make=$2\+$3\+$4&model=all&price=all [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)/([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /searchresults.php?search=1&year_search_type=single&isused=all&year=$1&make=$2\-$3\+$4&model=all&price=all [L,NC]
```

the first rule should be filtering out any string that the year is whatever and the make is a "wordDASHwordSPACEword" while the second one does the same except its looking for "wordSPACEwordSpaceword"

but only the first one works. Both work perfectly except when written second.

this voodoo is voodoo.

if you want the query rewrite info also here it is:(i have it before the the rules above that are not working properly... but moving it below or above made no difference)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  \?.*[&]isused=(\S+).*&year=([0-9]+).*&make=([^\%20]+)\+([^&\s]+)\+([^&\s]+).*&model=(all).*&price=(all).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %3 !=all
RewriteCond %2 !=all
RewriteRule . /%2/%3-%4-%5? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  \?.*[&]isused=(\S+).*&year=([0-9]+).*&make=([^\%20]+)\-([^&\s]+)\+([^&\s]+).*&model=(all).*&price=(all).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %3 !=all
RewriteCond %2 !=all
RewriteRule . /%2/%3-%4-%5? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: can i use RewriteCond on the single line rewrite rules? if so what would be in {} instead of THE_REQUEST?

Comment: The two patterns are exactly the same, so if it matches the first one, the first rule gets applied and the second one is ignored.

Comment: one is searching for a - and the other is searching for a + that is the only difference between the two rules, but i dont understand why a - is being seen as the same as a +

Comment: The patterns **are identical**, `^/?([^/]*)/([^/]*)-([^/]*)-([^/]*)$` is the same pattern for both rules. The only way a rule gets applied is if the URI matches that pattern, if two rules have the exact same pattern, the second one obviously will never get applied.

Comment: maybe i am misunderstanding how the rule works... i was under the impression that the second half of it was the pattern that is matched(with the $1 and so on)  , hence having the whole string with variables in it and the first part that is identical is the OUTPUT? mainly because the output is word/word/word  and the input is ?something=something&somethignelse=somethignelse

Comment: so confused. all my rules work except those two. just under 70 lines of htaccess.. for different query combinations.